# Wordpress site overloads the server, shutting down db gets server normal

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux-networking, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04

Hi I have a wordpress site running on EC2 and RDS. All of a sudden the site won't load and on investigating I see that the server load is at 15 and increasing rapidly.

I remove access of this EC2 from the RDS security group and the server gets back to normal. Now has a load of 0.07

The moment I allow the server to connect with the db that is the RDS the load spikes and server gets irresponsive.

I suspect its a hack? I have daily backups of both EC2 and RDS and can restore it to a state when it was working well, but I want to find out what is causing this. This has happened before when I had updated the plugins and back then I had just done a restore to a previous state and everything got back to working.

Can someone guide me into how I can pinpoint what script or backdoor is open and causing this?

Additional Data

The site is running behind cloudflare so I doubt that it is DDOS attack.

Here is a screen grab of htop with access to RDS enabled

[image]

Comment: The first step is to use "top" or similar to find out what's using CPU. Next I'd look in the web server access / errors logs to see if there's anything interesting there. Could just be a high load, or DDOS. Once you've done that please edit your question to add information you found. Right now there's nothing to go on.

Comment: Also check the process list on rds. I had a single plugin have 5 stuck processes on rds causing exactly the same symptoms

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info provided from the screenshot, you are short on RAM.  So the swap goes to the roof (seen on your screenshot too), making your CPU wait, slowing down your drives, piling up NginX and Apache processes, intensifying RAM requirements, making CPU wait even more, etc...

So my recommendations would be to:
1) pump up the RAM
2) reduce the swapiness

Following the RAM adjustment, more adjustments on different levels (i.e. CPU) could be required.